# check whether the html is present in another div or not using jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

This is my code, I got the html when `td` is clicked,It works fine. But what i need is to check that html is present in another div or not using jquery. If present I want to highlighted those html parts.

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
   $('#preview').on("click", "td", function() {
        alert($(this).html());
    });
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="pre">
    Hi // this is what i need output and this html is same i want to highlight this text.
```

```
    <div id="preview">
    Hi    // get this output using click function
</div>
```

Comment: Please share in more details.

Comment: try     if($('#id').html()==''){//do your stuff}else{//do something}

Comment: @dreamweiver Stop editing greetings into questions, Stack Overflow is not a message board.

Comment: @JamieTaylor: i thought its lot more formal that way.

Comment: @dreamweiver [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0):

From your question all i can infer is you want to show the contents of 'pre' into preview

```
if($('#pre').html()==''){}
else{
    $('#preview').html($('#pre').html());
}
```

Comment: after i shown the html if we click on that html output particular html will be highlighted in the pre div

Comment: You can use string operations to check how many times the clicked part exists in the string to be highlighted